How to always show scroll bar on scheduler timeline wiew
I want the scroll bar to always be visible. It appears when I start scrolling, but I want it to always be visible.
so
#scheduler .k-scheduler-content {
    overflow-y: scroll;
    } 

this is not working
please give some exaple on schedule timeline view
demo url -> https://dojo.telerik.com/vYopoCvR/10
i tried like this but  As in the picture, a slip occurred due to vertical scrolling.
